# 'Parse/PFFile.h' file not found after Pod update

Tags: ios, swift

I have big issues, today i want to update POD's in my project, after update i immediately get lot of error but i fix it except one.

I use **ParseUI** pod at my project, after pod update i got such error:

> 'Parse/PFFile.h' file not found

My podFile:

```
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'ParseUI'
```

After searching at network, i found nothing, how i can fix this error?

I work with **Swift 4.2**

Error image :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello fellow Parse user!

`pod 'ParseUI'` is deprecated and you should use `pod 'Parse/UI'` instead.
Change that, delete your pods folder and podfile.lock. Run  `pod install --repo-update` from your app directory and hopefully you will have resolved the issue.

You do not need to import ParseUI within your app any longer. Importing "Parse" now imports all things related to Parse, such as ParseUI, Parse/TwitterUtils and Parse/FacebookUtils. Only import "Parse" and you have access to everything.

Comment: After this steps i got new error - "No such module 'ParseUI'"

Comment: Where does this error occur? Wherever it does, you need to make sure that reference which now can not find "ParseUI" looks for and uses "Parse/UI"

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention. You do not need to import ParseUI any longer. Importing "Parse" now imports all things related to Parse, such as ParseUI, Parse/TwitterUtils and Parse/FacebookUtils. Only import "Parse" and you can use everything.

Comment: Thank you for help.

Comment: No problem, please accept my answer if you find it now complete with the edits I've made.

Comment: A minor convenience: I find it tons easier to comment out the soon-to-be-changed pod, do a pod install, then set the Podfile to the correct listing, and run the pod install again.  Simpler.